# why can't my content appear on click like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've wrote a `javascript` to show a hidden content but it just won't show up when i click it, can anyone help me with this?

Here's my script:

```
<script src="style/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(
         function(){
             $("#yes").click(
                    function(){
                         $("div#did").show();
                        }
                )
            }
         function(){
             $("#no").click(
                    function(){
                         $("div#did_not").show();
                        }
                )
            }
        )
</script>
```

My css file to hide it:

```
#did{
 display: none;
}
#did_not{
     display: none;
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<button id="yes">Yes</button>
<button id="no">No</button>

<div id="did">
     <p>
        Yes
     <p/>
</div>
<div id="did_not">
     <p>
         No
     </p>
</div>
```

Help me here!

Comment: it's show(), you are missing parenthesis. should be $("div#did").show();

Comment: change show to show()

Comment: `.ready()` accepts 1 function as parameter, you've put two one after the other as a single parameter, which is meaningless. Remove the `} function(){` from the middle of your code...

Comment: and it still don't...Shai...

Comment: yes, i admit that...

Answer (score 3):

While the *reason* it didn't work has been answered (syntax errors), I'd suggest simplifying your code to:

```
$('button').on('click', '#yes, #no', function(){
    $('#did' + (this.id === 'yes' ? '' : '_not')).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xs9rz31c/).

Assuming only *one* response (given the Boolean nature of the answers 'yes'/'no') should be visible:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var response = $.trim($(this).text());
    $('div.response').hide().filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === response;
    }).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xs9rz31c/).

References:

- [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/trim/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: It does work, though I had to add the parentheses around the ternary to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code has some syntax error, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yes").click(function(){
        $("div#did").show();
    })

    $("#no").click(function(){
        $("div#did_not").show();
    })
});
```

[**Check JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xpdk0gyw/)

Comment: Are you familiar with JSFiddle? you can check the JSFiddle Demo to see it's work correctly, if it's not work in your project maybe you don't include JQuery correctly, check `<script src="style/jquery/jquery.js"></script>` and try to check javascript errors in browser.

Answer (score 0):

`show` is a function not a property. So you have to add `()` to make it work.

```
$("div#did_not").show();
```

Because you are defining thing as function and you are not calling that

```
$(document).ready(
         function(){
             $("#yes").click(function(){
                         $("div#did").show();
                        })
            }(),  //here you have to call the function to make it work by adding parentheses 
         function(){
             $("#no").click(function(){
                         $("div#did_not").show();
             })
            }()
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/64/)

Comment: it could be comment and ya it still don't

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the true problem:

I've forgotten that `../` before that `style/jquery/jquery.js`